# Error creating System.Type from string "System.Int32"

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik

On a web site I published (pre-compiled) last night, I get the following error. Before pre-compiling it, I was getting a compiler error that a User Control was not found. After compiling on another machine, and running, I get the following Parser error:

```
"Cannot create an object of type 'System.Type' from its srting representation 'System.Int32' for the 'DataType' property"
```

was the, now runtime, parser error I got.  The offending tag is
    telerik:RadNumericTextBox .... DataType="System.Int32"...

I emphasise again that this error only occurs on XP SP2, not on Vista and Win7.  I'm off to do some Googling and issue logging at Telerik.

Comment: Added telerik tag since this looks telerik specific.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't stop to think that there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of this problem isn't just Telerik, but ASP.NET not being able to interpret the string representation.  I just tried this on a small test project, with no Telerik, and I get the same error.

This is not to say the haven't fixed it, but I would be impressed to see how they did.  It is easily done with two properties, one that takes a string and gets a type from it, and sets the actual type property, but that gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in one of my projects and it disappeared when I moved to the latest release Q1 2009 SP1.

Dick

Comment: I upgraded the DLL Telerik.Web.UI.dll to the 2009 Q2 controls (version 2009.02.0701.20) and the build errors were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that there is a `GetType`-type-of-resolution somewhere inside Telerik that is failing. It may be worth trying adding the assembly name to the string if this happens
e.g.: `"System.Int32, mscorlib"` ...